# What is the difference between closed system and open system esignature?

Tags: java, signature, electronic-signature

I need to find a solution for one of my clients who is asking me to implement a esignature solution. I was thinking of suggesting some solutions like DocuSign or EchoSign.

But recently my client said he wants a closed system esignature.

I searched some sites and i found out the difference between closed system and open system esignature.

http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfCFR/CFRSearch.cfm?CFRPart=11&showFR=1

The Closed system means an environment in which system access is controlled by persons who are responsible for the content of electronic records that are on the system.

And the Open system means an environment in which system access is not controlled by persons who are responsible for the content of electronic records that are on the system.

My understanding from this is that i can't suggest Docusign or EchoSign anymore. Am i correct?
And one more question , Do i need to create my very own esignature solution for this or is there any libraries or framework available?

Comment: @axrwkr: I don'tknow. Maybe they don't want to save any document in cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the important part of that document is this:

> Persons who use closed systems to create, modify, maintain, or
>   transmit electronic records shall employ procedures and controls
>   designed to ensure the authenticity, integrity, and, when appropriate,
>   the confidentiality of electronic records, and to ensure that the
>   signer cannot readily repudiate the signed record as not genuine. Such
>   procedures and controls shall include the following:

My interpretation of that is a closed system is one that appropriate security measures have been taken.

Judging by that DocuSign would qualify.  I'm currently working with DocuSign to enable our web site to send documents to our customers to sign.  When the process is done, we not only need to save the documents that were signed, but a summary document that describes the process the documents went through to be signed.  I'm no lawyer, but in my opinion, DocuSign would satisfy the requirements.  I would guess that other e signature companies do comparable things...